# What exactly is one MongoDB Atlas Credit?

Tags: azure, mongodb-atlas

I'm evaluating the use of MongoDB Cloud (Atlas) in Azure, you have three options:

- **MongoDB Cloud- Atlas Free Tier**: Free Tier provides access to Atlas M0 shared instance, which includes 512 MB of storage. This is ideal for learning MongoDB, prototyping, and early development. Once you are ready to upgrade, you can buy MongoDB Atlas Credits by selecting one of the other options on this page or write to mdb-azure-marketplace@mongodb.com for a custom offer.
- **MongoDB Cloud - Atlas Starter Pack**:  Starter Pack includes 1,800 MongoDB Atlas Credit, valid for 1 year. It does NOT include Premium Support. Credits consumption is based on cluster type, network transfer, backup and support.
  Doesn’t fit your needs? Write to mdb-azure-marketplace@mongodb.com for a custom offer.
- **MongoDB Cloud - Atlas Pro Pack (Premium Support)**: Pro Pack with 25,000 Credits, valid for 1 year. It includes Atlas Pro (premium) Support with 2 hr response time SLA. Credits consumption is based on cluster type, network transfer, backup and support.
  Doesn’t fit your needs? Write to mdb-azure-marketplace@mongodb.com for a custom offer.

But, What exactly is a MongoDB Atlas Credit, in terms of processing power, data transfer, storage and other types of resources?

Without knowing it I cannot choose the right option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One credit is worth 1 USD. The Azure Pricing in the portal also gives you an indication of this.

See this screen, though my prices are in Euro:
[image: Azure Cost pricing]

Based on this information, you can use the [cluster configuration costs](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/billing/cluster-configuration-costs). The actual costs vary across regions.

> For a three-member replica set with 30GB of data, Atlas charges US$72.50 each month (using the default backup rate).
>
> (30 GB - 1 GB) × US$2.50 = US$72.50
>
> A sharded cluster with 3 shards contains 90GB of data, with each shard containing 30GB of data each. The config server replica set contains 5GB of data.
>
> For this sharded cluster, Atlas charges US$227.50 per month (using the default backup rate).
>
> ((30 GB - 1 GB) × US$2.50) × 3) + ((5 GB - 1 GB) × US$2.50) = US$227.50